# Custom AuthorizationHandler getting invoked even for expired token in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I have created a custom `AuthorizationHandler` in my ASP.NET Core 6 application.

When I call the endpoint with an expired token, the handler is getting invoked. Is this expected?

As this is causing problem, since I am injecting services inside this handler, which read claims in their constructors. And the claims are not present.

Comment: What’s the authentication you are using, how you implement it? Could you please share your code of AuthorizationHandler?

Comment: Using bearer authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a real situation and we usually use it this way, the authorization will still be called even if the authentication failed. It can provide convenience in many cases.

If your don't want to waste too much resource to the authorization, you can handle this through the Identity.

```
protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
{
    Console.WriteLine("entering");
    //check the status
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("still executing");
    var permissions = context.User.Claims.Where(_ => _.Type == "Permission").Select(_ => _.Value).ToList();
    if (permissions.Any(_ => _.StartsWith(requirement.Name)))
    {
        context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("executed");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

And it works well in my environment.

[image]

Here is the .net core document. https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11609